# missing arguments for method in trait Iterator

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie to Scala working through the [Beginning Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219890) book and I can't seem to get an example working.  I've checked numerous times and I can't seem to find where my code deviates.  I've got the following scala file:

```
import scala.io._

def toInt(in: String): Option[Int] =
  try {
    Some(Integer.parseInt(in.trim))
  } catch {
    case e: NumberFormatException => None
  }

def sum(in: Seq[String]) = {
  val ints = in.flatMap(s => toInt(s))
  ints.foldLeft(0)((a, b) => a + b)
}

println("Enter some numbers and press ctrl-D)")

val input = Source.fromInputStream(System.in)
val lines = input.getLines.collect

println("Sum "+sum(lines))
```

Every time I attempt to run using the command `Scala sum.scala`, I get the following error:

```
sum.scala:18: error missing arguments for method collect in trait Iterator:
follow this method with '_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
val lines = input.getLines.collect
                           ^
one error found
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to collect? To get sum of numbers on each line there is no need to call collect:

```
val lines = input.getLines.toList
println("Sum "+sum(lines))
```

or via standart scala functions:

```
val numbers = input.getLines.map(line => line.trim.toInt)
println("Sum "+numbers.sum)
```

Comment: I changed the .collect to .toList and everything worked properly - thanks for the help!